# Get checkbox dynamically selected based on database values using JSF

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

There is a list of items in UI and every row has unique ID attached to it. First of all, this column would be visible only for certain users. And the checkbox must be `checked + disabled` based on certain conditions. As of now, the checkbox is getting disabled and except the first row, all other checkboxes are getting checked. Could someone suggest some ideas to make this happen?

The boolean value **partTypeAwarded** is not part of the database column. Am using `JSF 2.1 + Primefaces 3.5`.

xhtml page:

```
<c:if test="#{(authorizationBean.abcRestrictedUser and authorizationBean.hasAbcPageAccess())}">
    <p:column headerText="#{msgs.abcAwarded}" styleClass="menuHeader" style="text-align:left">
        <p:selectBooleanCheckbox styleClass="margin_left_10" value="#{abcBean.partTypeAwarded}"
                 disabled="#{true}">
        </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
    </p:column>
</c:if>
```

AbcBean

```
@URLAction(onPostback = false)
    public void load() {
        currentProject = projectService.findProject(projectId);
        allBajajVersions = bajajService.getBajajVersionsForProject(currentProject);
        awardedPartsTypeList = bajajPartSheetService.findQAPartTypeAwarded(projectId);    

    }

public boolean isPartTypeAwarded() {
        return partTypeAwarded;
}

public void setPartTypeAwarded(boolean partTypeAwarded) {
    this.partTypeAwarded = partTypeAwarded;
}



public boolean isPartTypeAwardedinAbc() {

        if (null != currentProject.getProjectPartTypes() && currentProject.getProjectPartTypes().size() > 0) {
            for (ProjectPartType projectPartType : currentProject.getProjectPartTypes()) {
                for (BajajPartsType awardedPartsType : awardedPartsTypeList) {                        
                    if (projectPartType.getBajajProjectPartsType().getName().equals(awardedPartsType.getName())) {                            
                        setPartTypeAwarded(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return partTypeAwarded;
    }
```

Comment: Try with a plain jsf `h:selectBooleanCheckbox`, without a database, without the c:if, without a column, without a database etc... or in other words... [mcve]... To much 'noise' to start investigating...

Comment: @BalusC: is there a way to check conditional rendering of selectBooleanCheckBox value coming from database ?

Comment: @Kukeltje : since the values are not being inputted from UI, but coming directly from database... and based on certain parameters, the values are set to either `false` or `true` ... just curious to know if `selectBooleanCheckBox` value could be conditionally rendered on the  `xhtml page`

Comment: This is not a [mcve]... and the answer to your last sentence is yes